# what can i do i got out when i am searching class then count how many student in class

Tags: javascript

```
let student = [{
 id:1,
 name:'aman',
 class:'10',
 gender:'male'

},{
 id:2,
 name:'shivani',
 class:'10',
 gender:'female'
},{
 id:2,
 name:'riyan',
 class:'11',
 gender:'female'
}]
```

```
function customFilter(objList, text) {
    if (undefined === text || text === '' ) return objList;
    return objList.filter(product => {
        let flag;
        for (let prop in product) {
            if (product[prop].toString().indexOf(text)>-1) {
                product[prop] = 0
                product[prop]++
                flag = product[prop]
                console.log(flag)
            }
        }
    return flag;
    });}
    
    console.log(customFilter(student, '10'))
```

I want the output of the number of students in a class. Example: when I pass class 10 as an argument then I should  get the output of how many students are in class 10
`output: {class:10,stduent:5 }`

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get your question well, but I assumed you want number of students in a class like this `{class:10, students: 2}`

```js
let student = [
  { id:1, name:'aman', class:'10', gender:'male'},
  { id:2, name:'shivani', class:'10', gender:'female' },
  { id:3, name:'riyan', class:'11', gender:'female' }
]
    
function customFilter(objList, text) {
  if (undefined === text || text === '' ) return objList;
  const numberOfStudents =  objList.filter(product => {
    for (let prop in product) {
      if (product[prop].toString().includes(text)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  });
  return {class:text, student:numberOfStudents.length}
}
        
console.log(customFilter(student, '10'))
```

If that's the case, this code will do.

Comment: Using `,indexOf()` here could be misleading to a maintainer, `.includes()` would suit the intent a little better and is more readable

Comment: Don't bother to track the count of occurrences in the filter function as that data will all be lost anyway.  If you need to track that, use `.reduce()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This would also work:

```js
let students = [
  { id: 1, name: "aman", class: "10", gender: "male" },
  { id: 2, name: "shivani", class: "10", gender: "female" },
  { id: 2, name: "riyan", class: "11", gender: "female" },
];

const customFilter = (students, key, value) => {
  const res = { [key]: value, student: 0 };
  students.forEach((student) => {
    if (student[key] === value) {
      res.student += 1;
    }
  });
  return res;
};

console.log(customFilter(students, "class", "10"));
```

Using [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: This changes the intent of the OPs code.  The OP's code is trying to find all elements of `objList` where the value of *any* property *contains* the search term.  Yours finds all elements of `objList` where the value of *a specified* property *equals* the search term

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems with the code. change `class:'10'` to `grade: 10,`.

- don't use "class" as a variable name. might cause a few errors
- There is a missing `,`
- numbers shouldn't be inside quotes because the number will be stored as a `string`

```js
let student = [
  { id: 1, name: 'aman', grade: 10, gender: 'male'},
  { id: 2, name: 'shivani', grade: 10, gender: 'female' }, 
  { id: 2, name: 'riyan', grade: 11, gender: 'female' },
]

function customFilter(objList, value){
  if(!value || value === '') return objList;

  let count = 0
  objList.forEach(obj => {
    const { grade } = obj;
    if(grade === value){
      count++;
    }
  })
  return {grade: 10, count};
}

console.log(customFilter(student, 10));
```

and `forEach` can be used instead of `filter`. It loops from start to end of an `array`

Comment: It is much more valuable to explain why not to so something (i.e. "Do not use reserved words such as "class" as variable names as this can easily cause errors") than just saying not to do something.  Providing a [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#keywords) is even more valuable.

Comment: The assumption that `grade` should be a number is not backed up by anything in the OP's question.  Changing datatypes because of this sort of assumption about data types often causes integration issues that can be difficult to debug and resolve.  Example: What if "10" is the name of a room, and room names could include things like "10a".  Your type assumption would literally cause working code to fail.

Answer (score 0):

- Use `.reduce()` to group all objects that match.

  ```js
  /* hits (accumulator) is initially an empty array.
     now (current) is the object of the current iteration. */

  array.reduce((hits, now) => { //...
  ```
- On each iteration, get all of the current object's values (in lower case) in an array.

  ```js
  Object.values(now).map(val => val.toLowerCase()) 

  /* result of the first object: ["01gn3z1ryjjqhn588ax3bws6qb", "theo bramstom", 
     "genderqueer", "english"] */
  ```
- If any of the values of the current object matches the given string (`term`), add the current object to the `hits` array.

  ```js
  if (Object.values(now)
       .map(val => val.toLowerCase()).includes(term.toLowerCase())) {
    hits.push(now);
  }
  ```
- An object literal is returned.

  ```js
  {
    "matches": /* an array of all matched objects */,
    "total": /* the .length of "matches" array */
  };

  /* To get the answer prompted in OP -- do the following */

  const x = dataFilter(students, "Math");
  console.log(x.total);
  ```

## ```js
// NOTE: key "class" is now "subject" just for aesthetics

const students=[{id:"01GN3Z1RYJJQHN588AX3BWS6QB",name:"Theo Bramstom",gender:"Genderqueer",subject:"English"},{id:"01GN3Z1RYM527HAX56ZN14F0YB",name:"Juli Marsy",gender:"Female",subject:"History"},{id:"01GN3Z1RYPYP1FFFEY55T92VX2",name:"Linc Espley",gender:"Non-binary",subject:"Math"},{id:"01GN3Z1RYR325M0QETVVPE2N5J",name:"Barbabas Grisley",gender:"Male",subject:"Math"},{id:"01GN3Z1RYTXA49SBQYXR9DMC04",name:"Godfree Braybrook",gender:"Male",subject:"English"},{id:"01GN3Z1RYVE4N5D16C8QWB1XGF",name:"Jason De Vuyst",gender:"Male",subject:"History"},{id:"01GN3Z1RYXY9WXF1Y407HXFYH8",name:"Adler McCanny",gender:"Male",subject:"Math"},{id:"01GN3Z1RYY9XV444J0SP5Y0QC2",name:"Noellyn MacMorland",gender:"Genderqueer",subject:"Math"},{id:"01GN3Z1RZ0HPQNZ1VKX8ZHA9ZY",name:"Padget Geldeford",gender:"Male",subject:"Math"},
{id:"01GN3Z1RZ2DZE92NG42KSGDXN9",name:"Milissent Treby",gender:"Female",subject:"Art"}];

const dataFilter = (array, term) => {
  let result = array.reduce((hits, now) => {
    if (Object.values(now).map(val => val.toLowerCase()).includes(term.toLowerCase())) {
      hits.push(now);
    }
    return hits;
  }, []);
  return {"matches": result, "total": result.length};
}

console.log(dataFilter(students, "Math"));
// Control case: term === "Math"
console.log(dataFilter(students, "PE"));
// No match case: term != "PE"
console.log(dataFilter(students, "female"));
// Case insensitive case: term === "Female"
```

Comment: Using `toLowerCase` needlessly changes the logic of the OP's code and may introduce errors.  "apples" != "Apples".

Comment: It's a common modification found in many search interfaces. Case insensitivity allows a modicum of flexibility wherein the user types in a word without having to needlessly capitalize a particular letter. When you do a search on Google, have you ever needed to use any upper case letters?

Comment: It might be common, doesn't mean it meets requirements (or was even a good idea in the first place).  Since there are no stated requirements, making assumptions that change the behavior of a piece of code is probably not a great idea

Comment: I've been making assumptions for the last 9 years answering questions. It's not like every person I've helped is in a chatroom conversing with me in real time -- to the contrary, many OPs aren't even present when I work on a question. Occasionally I'll get an answer accepted 2 or more years later. So to get the *"ball rolling"* I and many other users will assume certain things and if the OP has a problem with something we address it if needed. The process of answering questions isn't rigid, it's fluid because you interact with human beings.

Comment: I've been getting paid for fixing issues caused by coders making invalid assumptions for more than 30 years.  Doesn't mean I'm right here, because the OP doesn't say that would be making an invalid assumption.  Best you can do is document what you believe the intent to be and then write code that implements that.  It's also an assumption that your rep implies you understand that.

Comment: Wow, I just glanced at some of your comments, and you should read them. Better yet read all of your  comments  in this post alone.  Wow, well good luck to you. BTW, since you know a better solution, you should submit an answer yourself.

Comment: So far you've used argumentum ad verecundiam and ad hominem.  Maybe you should go for the trifecta.  Oh, no... wait.  You *started* with  ad antiquitatem.  You win.

Comment: You need to chill out. You're a very angry person and your hostility is unwarranted.  I win? Great then we never need to converse with each other again, good luck with that curmudgeon vibe you got going on there.